# Turn grepl into a function

Tags: r, lapply, grepl

the idea ist quite simple: Identify levels of data.frame and extract all rows with a certain level and write it into a new data.frame.

So a very bad solution should look like this.

```
table <- as.data.frame(table)
table$X4[duplicated(table$X4)]
id_list <-levels(factor(table$X4))
id_df <- as.data.frame(id_list)
row_number <- nrow(id_df)

table$a <- grepl(pattern = id_df[1,1], table$X4)
cow1 <- table[table$a == TRUE, ]
table$b <- grepl(pattern = id_df[2,1], table$X4)
cow2 <- table[table$b == TRUE, ]
table$c <- grepl(pattern = id_df[3,1], table$X4)
cow3 <- table[table$c == TRUE, ]
table$d <- grepl(pattern = id_df[4,1], table$X4)
cow4 <- table[table$d == TRUE, ]
```

I know that the basic function should look like something like this to do the deed and avoid copy$pasting of code

```
for(i in 1:nrow) 
{
 table$[i] <- grepl(pattern = id_df[i,1], table$X4)
 print(table)
 }
```

Comment: Sounds like a really simple solution, but would prefer if you can use `dput(table)` to give us a minimal reproducible example so I can confirm the code works before posting an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the `split()` function?

```
mylist <- split(iris, iris$Species)
```

`mylist` is a list of data frames, the list items having names corresponding to factor level names.

Print a single data frame

```
mylist$setosa
```

To print  all new dataframes:

`lapply(mylist, print)`

If you know the factor levels in advance  (and there is only 1 factor column):

`mylist <- split(iris, c("setosa", "virginica")) # a list of two data frames`